# Enable GLX extension in Xvfb in Xquartz

Tags: macos, xvfb, xquartz

The version of Xvfb included in Xquartz on MacOS doesn't support GLX:

```
$ Xvfb +extension GLX
[mi] Extension "GLX" is not recognized
[mi] Only the following extensions can be run-time enabled:
[mi]    Generic Events
[mi]    Composite
 ...
```

Is it feasible to enable it?  What is involved?

Edited to add:  I tried running Xvfb with the GLX extension on a Linux VM.  It runs fine, but it doesn't actually render the OpenGL graphics.  Perhaps I used the wrong config for the display.  I used

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 +extension GLX +render -noreset -fbdir temp >xsession.log 2>&1 &
```

or perhaps Xvfb just doesn't render OpenGL.

Comment: From the first message I'd say that _if_ GLX is available for Xvfb, it has to be compiled in, so to enable it you'd have to recompile your own version with appropriate configure flags...